# What are address26 and address29 in Nominatim?

Tags: nominatim

Occasionally - rarely - a Nominatim search will return a hit with a key "address29" or "address26".  There is no mention of such a key in osm, and I can't find any explanation in Nominatim.

Here's an example. Search nominatim for bamako (the capital city of Mali). Among others you'll see:

```
{"place_id":"104544188","licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright",
"osm_type":"way","osm_id":"197528638","boundingbox":["47.4519905","47.4523668","-0.5565341","-0.5561207"],"lat":"47.4519905","lon":"-0.5565341",
"display_name":"Bamako, Angers, Maine-et-Loire, Pays de la Loire, Metropolitan France, 49000;49100, France",
"class":"highway","type":"platform","importance":0.2,
"address":{"address26":"Bamako","city":"Angers","county":"Angers","state":"Pays de la Loire","country":"France","postcode":"49000;49100","country_code":"fr"},"namedetails":{"name":"Bamako"}},
```

In the address field/object you see "address26":"Bamako".  What does that mean? the other keys all make sense.

If you access the osm id: (eg, http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details?osmtype=W&osmid=197528638), there is no mention of address26.

At the website: https://thefive.sabic.uberspace.de/ they have a number of address26 entries pointing to Nominatim.  I don't know what their database represents.

I have come across other Nominatim search results with address29 instead of address26.

If you look at http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/, you won't find address26 or address29 as keys or tags...

Once in a while you will see a city named "fixme" on an osm map, but at least you have an idea of what's going on there, address2[69] stumps me.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you found out yet what they mean? I came across "address100" and don't know how to deal with it. Here's an example: 
{"place_id":"145104131","licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright","osm_type":"relation","osm_id":"4647396","lat":"47.21741055","lon":"-1.55473173623","display_name":"Centre Ville (canton de Nantes-1), France","address":{"address100":"Centre Ville (canton de Nantes-1)","country":"France","country_code":"fr"},"boundingbox":["47.2132641","47.221637","-1.5626391","-1.5466104"]}

Comment: you're missing osm's class and type fields.  they are what you need when you see things like address100, address29, etc.  they tell you what the item is.  although "centre ville" is a quarter in the city of nantes, france, the city tag is missing too.  something is wrong with the record.  address100 could be a placeholder in such cases.  address29, etc are bothersome, but osm's class and type are the keys to what you're looking at.  i'm pretty sure address29 is for businesses.  the others, i don't know...

Comment: address29 is not only for bussiness, someone maket with it the Government of the Republic of Moldova. Ex: `{address29:"Cabinet of Moldova", city: "Kishinev", country: "Moldova", country_code: "md", county: "Municipiul Chișinău", house_number: "1", pedestrian:"Piaţa Mării Adunări Naţionale", postcode: "MD-2012"}`

Comment: Looks like a nest of address29's in Moldova...
"address":{"address29":"Iosip Andrei","house_number":"41D","road":"Strada Armenească","suburb":"Centru","city":"Kishinev","county":"Municipiul Chisinau","postcode":"2012","country":"Moldova","country_code":"md"},"namedetails":{"name":"Iosip Andrei","name:ro":"Cabinet de Avocat IOSIP Andrei","name:ru":"Иосип Андрей"}