# address29 field in nominatim reverse geocoding api?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

Hello every one while exploring alternative to google maps reverse Geo-coding service i have come across openstreet map nominatim service but i cant seem to figure out what is the address29 field in the address object returned in the response

for eg i hit the api 
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=24.9128455&lon=67.002839&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

no address29 field is shown but when i hit this url

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=24.9128455&lon=67.0032436&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

you can see the field

Comment: Please provide more details...

Comment: @scai what more details are required?

Comment: Your geocoding request and the geocoding response. Otherwise we don't know what your question is about.

Comment: ok editing in a second

Comment: There is no "address29" field in the response:

`{"place_id":258268446,"licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"way","osm_id":681780721,"lat":"24.9129447808622","lon":"67.0027634765525","display_name":"Sindh Industrial Trading Estate, Karatschi, Karāchi District, Sindh, 75840, Pakistan","address":{"industrial":"Sindh Industrial Trading Estate","city":"Karatschi","county":"Karāchi District","state":"Sindh","postcode":"75840","country":"Pakistan","country_code":"pk"},"boundingbox":["24.9091911","24.9141245","66.9978291","67.0043143"]}`

Comment: @scai check update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been partly answered at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36143055/1340631):

> you're missing osm's class and type fields. they are what you need
>   when you see things like address100, address29, etc.

From my understanding, fields such as `address29` are specific address parts for which there is no description yet defined in Nominatim.

In your case, `"address29":"AGP Limited"` comes from the [`short_name`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:name) tag of [node 6556946279](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/6556946279). The short_name is a commonly used abbreviation of the name.

Comment: can you please tell me where in the api should i use these fields and what are the possible value for them?

Comment: You don't need to "use" them. Just ignore them if you don't intend to handle them. In case of the name the value can be arbitrary.